# Netsuite : Restrict User to see another mail

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

when user login to advanced partner center role and they go to any record like project / customer / any transaction.
they should be able to see communications > emails > 
only what they sent out and they received, they should not see others emails.
Is this possible ???

Answer (score 0):

You could create a custom view for each of the records that had criteria `Author is Mine Or Recipient is Mine` and then only give them access to that view.